# Обращение к элементам вин форм

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаю в учебных целях программу для решения судоку, возник вопрос, можно ли динамически обращаться к данным текстбоксам, чтобы считать значения с текстбоксов и закинуть в массив? про датагрид вкурсе, просто имхо вариант с использованием текстбоксов лучше..

```
    string k = "textbox",temp;
int l=1;
int[][] myarr;

for (int i=0;i<9;i++)
  for (int j=0;j<9;i++)
  {

    temp = k + l.Tostring();
    myarray[i][j] = temp.value();
    l++;
  }
```

прошу не кидаться помидорами, сам понимаю что за глупость написал в коде, просто интересны сами варианты как можно так сделать? даже вопрос правильно в гугле не смог придумать..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow.

```
string boxId = k + l.Tostring(); // или k + "_" + i.ToString() + "_" + j.ToString();

// panel - контрол, на котором находятся все TextBox-ы
TextBox box = panel.FindControl(boxId) as TextBox;
int value;
if (box != null && int.TryParse(box.Text, out value)) 
{
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем получилось такого рода решение, оставляю, вдруг кому пригодится

```
        int[,] myarr = new int [9,9];
        int l = 1, value;
        string k = "textbox", boxId;
        TextBox box;

        for(int i = 0; i<9;i++)
            for(int j = 0; j<9;j++)
            {
                boxId = k + l.ToString();
                l++;
                box = this.Controls.Find(boxId, true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
                if (box != null && int.TryParse(box.Text, out value))
                {
                    myarr[i, j] = int.Parse(box.Text);
                }
            }
```